# assigning function pointer to array of function pointers

Tags: c, arrays, static, initialization, function-pointers

In the below code, I am trying to assign function pointer to array of function pointers. I get the error message

> error: initializer element is not constant and then a note says near initialization for 'stateTable2[1]'.

In `main`, I tried to assign function pointer to another function pointer and no issue.

```
void function1 (void) // Function definition
{

}

void function2 (void) // Function definition
{

}

void (*fptr)(void) = function2;

void (*stateTable2[]) (void) = {function1,fptr};

int main()
{
    void(*fp)(void) = fptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In main, you are declaring, not assigning. Just try `fptr = function1;`

Comment: In `main` you have an initialization at runtime. As with assignments you don't need constant expression here. For initialization of data objects with static duration you need a constant expression.

Comment: ... therefore `void (*stateTable2[]) (void) = {function1,fptr};` -> `void (*stateTable2[]) (void) = {function1, function2};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not initialize an array with the static storage duration with a non-constant object.

Either declare the array like

```
void (*stateTable2[]) (void) = { function1, function2 };
```

or move the declaration

```
void (*stateTable2[]) (void) = {function1,fptr};
```

inside main making the array as an array with automatic storage duration.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function1 (void) // Function definition
{
    printf( "Hello " );
}

void function2 (void) // Function definition
{
    puts( "World!" );
}

void (*fptr)(void) = function2;

int main(void) 
{
    void ( *stateTable2[] ) (void) = { function1, fptr };
    void(*fp)(void) = fptr;

    fp();

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( stateTable2 ) / sizeof( *stateTable2 ); i++ )
    {
        stateTable2[i]();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
World!
Hello World!
```

Comment: How come preprocessor can understand the function name but not function pointer? I thought initializing fptr happens during preprocessing (hence it is known during compile time). But it looks this is not the case.

Comment: @Rajesh: You might want to elaborate more on what you mean.